# Using Created HttpWebResponse Interface Returns 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-401

So I originally had this code for the web request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

which I changed to this in order to add unit tests:

```
IHttpWebRequest request = IHttpWebRequestFactory.Create(uri);
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
IWebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

IHttpWebRequest:

```
public interface IHttpWebRequest
{
    bool UseDefaultCredentials { get; set; }
    IWebResponse GetResponse();
}
```

MyHttpWebRequest:

```
public class MyHttpWebRequest : IHttpWebRequest
{
    private readonly HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest;
    private bool useDefaultCredentials;

    public MyHttpWebRequest(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
    {
        this.httpWebRequest = httpWebRequest;
    }

    public bool UseDefaultCredentials
    {
        get { return useDefaultCredentials;  }
        set { useDefaultCredentials = value; }
    }

    public IWebResponse GetResponse()
    {
        return new MyWebResponse((HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse());
    }
}
```

IHttpWebRequestFactory:

```
public interface IHttpWebRequestFactory
{
    IHttpWebRequest Create(string Uri);
}
```

HttpWebRequestFactory:

```
public class HttpWebRequestFactory : IHttpWebRequestFactory
{
    public IHttpWebRequest Create(string Uri)
    {
        return new MyHttpWebRequest((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uri));
    }
}
```

IWebResponse:

```
public interface IWebResponse
{
    Stream GetResponseStream();
}
```

MyWebResponse:

```
public class MyWebResponse : IWebResponse
{
    private WebResponse webResponse;

    public MyWebResponse(HttpWebResponse webResponse)
    {
        this.webResponse = webResponse;
    }

    public Stream GetResponseStream()
    {
        return webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    }
}
```

But the website now returns a HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized. Using Fiddler works though. I also tried setting `request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`, `request.PreAuthenticate = true`, etc. but to no avail. :(

I also tried supplying my username and password to Credentials but the unauthorized error still appears, which is odd since the original code above works. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `useDefaultCredentials` correctly, try this:

MyHttpWebRequest:

```
public class MyHttpWebRequest : IHttpWebRequest
{
    private readonly HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest;

    public MyHttpWebRequest(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
    {
        this.httpWebRequest = httpWebRequest;
    }

    public bool UseDefaultCredentials
    {
        get { return this.httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials;  }
        set { this.httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = value; }
    }

    public IWebResponse GetResponse()
    {
        return new MyWebResponse((HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse());
    }
}
```